# Anonymous user form submission

Tags: 7, users

I have a situation where after doing the basic registration the user is redirected to a page where he needs to fill a small form.

I aim at implementing the `hook_user_insert()` and `hook_menu()` to do something like this

```
function registration_user_insert(&$edit, $account, $category){
  drupal_goto('splan/'.$edit['uid']);
}

function registration_menu() {
  $items['splan/%'] = array(
    'title' => 'Select a Plan',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('selectplan_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
  );

  return $items;
}
```

In `selectplan_form()` I will define my new form and then, using the user ID, I would save data into user table.

The basic user registration form is being submitted, the user is redirected to splan/uid, but I also get the following error.

> You are not authorized to access this page.

I have changed permissions to allow anonymous users to create and edit webform, but the problem still persists.

Comment: Why are you redirecting the user, instead of adding your form fields to the user profile form?

Comment: this situation is forced upon..i know i can add them in the user profile form but the requirements are not like that..

Comment: Then maybe a multi-step registration form instead?

Answer (score 1):

Implementing `hook_user_insert()` this way (calling `drupal_goto()` inside) is plain wrong:

- if there are any other implementations of this hook in other modules meant to be called after yours, they will not get called at all
- if for whatever reason `hook_user_insert()` from user module will not be called before your implementation, the user will not be saved at all
- if you look at `user_save()` function in user.module, you'll see that after invoking 'insert' hook there are many other things this function is doing, so if you use `drupal_goto()`, they will not be done.

What you can do though is to add your own submit function to `user_register_form`, and in that function set `$form_state['redirect']` to wherever you want (note that updating `$form_state['redirect']` in `hook_form_alter()` will not work in this case, as `user_register_submit()` sets its own redirect, so you need to do it after this - hence the need for your own submit).

Answer (score 0):

How about using the LoginToboggan module to create a temporary role for the user after signing up and giving that role the permissions needed?